# Link to specific Location in Iframe

Tags: iframe, hyperlink, hashtag

For about 23 years I have used "local" HTML with a little javascript to keep notes on many things.  My sites have an index of links to the left that target an iframe (named "content").  The iframe is on the right side.

My index links are written as follows:

```
<a class="index1" href="aa_HTML-Page_.htm#Linkname1" target="content">Linkname1</a><br>
```

I have always used "#Name of ID" to take me to a specific location on the page loaded in the iframe.  Since Explorer went away, I can't get it to work like that.

The id attribute in any page loaded in the Iframe are written as follows:

```
<h2 id="Linkname1" class="left">Linkname1</h2>
```

The links to any page work and load the page, but links to IDs (specific locations) do not work.

I have tried changing the scrolling or height of the iframe thinking it might have to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah that is no longer supported in modern browsers, except maybe Safari, so you might what to try it on a Mac or iPad.

I wrote a library a while back that adds this functionality back into the browser, so you might want to try that, it’s called [iframe-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer) and deals with a number of headaches with using iframes.

That said do you really need an iframe to do this, the same effect could be achived with just CSS these days.

Comment: I've done a quick search.  Could you point me to a resource or give me an example of using CSS?  What exactly would I be targeting if not the name of an iframe, maybe a div element?
Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Yeah you would put the content of each iframe in a different div and then use just a little JS to hide and show them.